Factoring polynomial in two variables (x,y), where y degree is at most 1.
From link, (,) with degree d can be factorized as (++)(,) only if line ax+by+c=0 and curve f(x,y) share more than d common points. This applies to the general two-var poloynomail f(x,y).
But what if the y's degree in f(x,y) (such as x^2+xy+1) is restricted to at most 1? My intuition is that only 2 common points is enough for factorization. Can any one give me a proof? Or my intuition is wrong?
For y's degree is at most 0, it degenerates to single-variable polynomial. And it can be easily proved. So I hypotheize it can be generalized to any k smaller than d, where k the y's degree and d is the function degree.
I am asking this as I am dealing with Circle FFT, which results into F(x,y) where y's degree is at most 1.
Much thanks!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
